# Music player error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I get an error in the first line of my music player code. How can I fix it?

> Error: Call can throw but its not marked with try and the error is not
>   handled

```
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: pianoSound as URL)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    var pianoSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "C", ofType: "m4a")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is possible to conclude from the error you get :

> Error: Call can throw but its not marked with try and the error is
>   not handled

Because `AVAudioPlayer` can throw exception you should use `do {} catch {}`

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "C", ofType:"m4a")!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {
    let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    sound.play()
} catch {
    // Catch exception
}
```

This is example of working prototype:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var boomSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "boom", ofType: "wav")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: boomSound as URL)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            // Catch exception
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: con not use member 'path' within property initializer, property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Yes I just want to simply play a sound by clicking a button. In the old versions of Xcode it worked like I posted above.